# What does "Slide on build" stand for in the PPt presentation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This expression is used in the speaker notes to some slides of PPt presentation.
I suppose that "build" stands for some content of a slide like diagrams or table with text or something like that. But I am not sure.

Comment: Try asking the speaker. Speakers' notes are sometimes little more than mnemonics.

Comment: I agree with Lawrence. Meanwhile an obvious interpretation would be *This slide is in the process of preparation*.

Answer (score -1):

Slide builds make complex slides more simple by showing one element at a time. Builds most often refer to showing one bullet point at a time. In this way the slide "builds". So if you have four bullet points, only the first one is shown until the speaker addresses that point. Then the speaker advances the presentation and brings up the next bullet point and addresses it, and so on. You can also build a slide with images so that only one image is showing to start the slide. The speaker addresses that image and then advances the slide to show the next image, or additional images one at a time. Again, this is a way to simplify complex slides.
Craig Seifferth